# Return multiple rows is PHP Query with same id

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, ssms

Im trying to get the page to display all the comments associated with the page. However it is only returning the first comment in the list.

```
$commentIdQuery = "SELECT commentid FROM COMMENT_RECIPE WHERE RecipeID = '$recipeID[0]'";
$CID = mssql_query($commentIdQuery, $connection);
$commentID = mssql_fetch_row($CID);
$commentQuery = "SELECT UserID, Rating, Comment FROM COMMENTS WHERE CommentID = '$commentID[0]'";
```

And then to print it i have

```
    while($row = mssql_fetch_row($commentQuery)){   
echo "<td> $row[0] $row[1] $row[2]<br><br></td>";           
}
```

Comment: It seems like you should really be joining the two queries into one here.

Comment: Does it only show one comment, or does it show multiple comments that are all the same?

Comment: I'm not sure how your DB is set up but I'd imagine that "CommentID" is actually a unique ID for each comment.  If so, in your first query you are only getting a single CommentID because instead of looping through the results you just assign the first CommentID returned to $commentID, and then querying on that of course would only return a single row.

Comment: It is only showing the first comment, I assume I need a while loop somewhere, do I have to place the $commentID into a loop?

Comment: I think you should be doing something like this, and then iterate through the whole result set: SELECT UserID, Rating, Comment FROM COMMENTS 
INNER JOIN COMMENT_RECIPE ON (COMMENTS.CommentID = COMMENT_RECIPE.commentid)
WHERE RecipeID = '$recipeID[0]'

Answer (score 0):

Try `JOINING` both the queries -

```
$query = "SELECT COMMENTS.UserId, COMMENT.Rating, COMMENT.Comment,
          COMMENT_RECIPE.commentid
          FROM COMMENT INNER JOIN COMMENT_RECIPE ON
          COMMENT.CommentID = COMMENT_RECIPE.commentid
          WHERE COMMENT_RECIPE.RecipeID = '$recipeID[0]'
         "; 
$execute = mssql_query($query, $connection);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>";
while($row = mssql_fetch_row($execute))
{
     echo "<tr>
      <td>$row[0]</td>
      <td>$row[1]</td>
      <td>$row[2]</td>
      </tr>";         
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: while($row = mssql_fetch_row($execute))
 {
     echo "<tr>
      <td>$row['UserId']</td>
      <td>$row['Rating']</td>
      <td>$row['Comment']</td>
      </tr>";         
 }

Breaks it

Comment: Really!! Now it has all the opening and closing tags.

Comment: even if i try to echo static output it breaks, if i leave the loop empty it loads the page at least